# Parallel Enabled Pipelined Table Functions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get a Parallel Enabled Pipelined Table Function to work on Oracle 19c, however, all the examples I have found reference a single table ROWTYPE. I need the ROWTYPE to be a cursor. My Sample code

```
CREATE TABLE parallel_country (
country_code    VARCHAR2 (5 BYTE),
country_name    VARCHAR2 (50 BYTE),
CONSTRAINT parallel_country_pk PRIMARY KEY (country_code)
 );

CREATE TABLE parallel_test (
id              NUMBER (10),
country_code    VARCHAR2 (5 BYTE),
description     VARCHAR2 (50 BYTE)
);

INSERT /*+ APPEND */
   INTO parallel_test
    SELECT LEVEL                                                                             
AS id,
           (CASE TRUNC (MOD (LEVEL, 4)) WHEN 1 THEN 'CA' WHEN 2 THEN 'UK' ELSE 'US' END)     AS country_code,
           'Description or ' || LEVEL                                                        
AS description
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100000;

COMMIT;


INSERT INTO parallel_country (country_code, country_name)
 VALUES ('CA', 'Canada');

INSERT INTO parallel_country (country_code, country_name)
 VALUES ('US', 'United States');

INSERT INTO parallel_country (country_code, country_name)
 VALUES ('UK', 'United Kingdom');

COMMIT;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE parallel_ptf_api
AS
TYPE t_parallel_test_row IS RECORD
(
    id              NUMBER (10),
    country_code    VARCHAR2 (5),
    description     VARCHAR2 (50),
    sid             NUMBER
);

TYPE t_parallel_cursor_row IS RECORD
(
    id              NUMBER (10),
    country_code    VARCHAR2 (5),
    description     VARCHAR2 (50),
    sid             NUMBER,
    country_name    VARCHAR2 (50)
);

CURSOR c_parallel_test_cursor IS
    SELECT /*+ parallel(t1, 5) */
           *
      FROM parallel_test t1 JOIN parallel_country USING (country_code);

TYPE t_parallel_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR
    RETURN c_parallel_test_cursor%ROWTYPE;

TYPE t_parallel_cursor_tab IS TABLE OF t_parallel_cursor_row;

FUNCTION test_ptf_open
    RETURN t_parallel_ref_cursor;

FUNCTION test_ptf_cursor (p_cursor IN t_parallel_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_cursor_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY ANY);

TYPE t_parallel_test_tab IS TABLE OF t_parallel_test_row;

TYPE t_parallel_test_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR
    RETURN parallel_test%ROWTYPE;

FUNCTION test_ptf_any (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY ANY);

FUNCTION test_ptf_hash (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY HASH (country_code));

FUNCTION test_ptf_range (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY RANGE (country_code));
 END parallel_ptf_api;
 /
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY parallel_ptf_api
 AS
FUNCTION test_ptf_open
    RETURN t_parallel_ref_cursor
IS
    l_cursor   t_parallel_ref_cursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_parallel_test_cursor;

    RETURN l_cursor;
END test_ptf_open;

FUNCTION test_ptf_cursor (p_cursor IN t_parallel_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_cursor_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY ANY)
IS
    l_row   t_parallel_cursor_row;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH p_cursor
            INTO l_row.id,
                 l_row.country_code,
                 l_row.description,
                 l_row.country_name;

        EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT sid
          INTO l_row.sid
          FROM sys.v_$mystat
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

        PIPE ROW (l_row);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END test_ptf_cursor;

FUNCTION test_ptf_any (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY ANY)
IS
    l_row   t_parallel_test_row;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH p_cursor INTO l_row.id, l_row.country_code, l_row.description;

        EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT sid
          INTO l_row.sid
          FROM sys.v_$mystat
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

        PIPE ROW (l_row);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END test_ptf_any;

FUNCTION test_ptf_hash (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY HASH (country_code))
IS
    l_row   t_parallel_test_row;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH p_cursor INTO l_row.id, l_row.country_code, l_row.description;

        EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT sid
          INTO l_row.sid
          FROM v$mystat
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

        PIPE ROW (l_row);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END test_ptf_hash;

FUNCTION test_ptf_range (p_cursor IN t_parallel_test_ref_cursor)
    RETURN t_parallel_test_tab
    PIPELINED
    PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_cursor BY RANGE (country_code))
IS
    l_row   t_parallel_test_row;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH p_cursor INTO l_row.id, l_row.country_code, l_row.description;

        EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT sid
          INTO l_row.sid
          FROM v$mystat
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

        PIPE ROW (l_row);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END test_ptf_range;
END parallel_ptf_api;
/

  SELECT country_code, sid, COUNT (*)
FROM TABLE (parallel_ptf_api.test_ptf_cursor 
(parallel_ptf_api.test_ptf_open ())) t2
GROUP BY country_code, sid
ORDER BY country_code, sid;


ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "PARALLEL_PTF_API", line 21
```

I understand why I'm getting the invalid cursor (because test_ptf_open opens c_parallel_test_cursor but returns l_cursor). I've tried OPEN ... FOR but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is exactly. We see a whole bunch of code... where is the problem?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the code you see the error